# values-night folder is triggered only from System theme change and not from app theme change

Tags: android, user-interface, android-dark-theme

I am trying to implement theme switching between dark and light theme. Created duplicate of values folder to values-night and defined two different colors for dark and light respectively. However,  while press button to switch the theme it does not works. Instead it works of Android system UI theme selection (Meaning if i switch theme from Android device settings menu.) I want to make it work when i click switch theme from my app.

Following code is used to switch theme:

```
if (isDarkModeOn) {
    System.out.println("Dark mode is on: so disable it");
    AppCompatDelegate.setDefaultNightMode(AppCompatDelegate.MODE_NIGHT_NO);
    btnTheme.setText("Enable Dark Mode");
} else {
    System.out.println("Dark mode is off: so enable it");
    AppCompatDelegate.setDefaultNightMode(AppCompatDelegate.MODE_NIGHT_YES);
    btnTheme.setText("Disable Dark Mode");
}
requireActivity().recreate();
```

App theme is also correctly set as:

```
<style name="AppTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.DayNight"></style>
```

Please suggest appropriate way to solve this. Thanks in advance.

Comment: I use material component theme and it works try it out. and I think you don't need to recreate activity as I know.

Comment: it is not working on App Compat theme. I need to make it work on App Compat theme. The main problem is it does not switch colors from two different folders auotmatically.

Comment: The code itself seems to be correct I think the problem is with your resources. check them out. and also I suggest defining global attributes in your main style. (add tags for text colors and backgrounds)

Comment: Global attributes in main style? How?

Comment: I will show you some sample in the form of an answer

Comment: Hello, were you able to resolve the issue? (facing something similar but only with drawable resources)

Answer (score 0):

Use some global attributes in your style

```
 <style name="AppTheme" parent="Theme.MaterialComponents.DayNight.NoActionBar">
    <!-- Customize your theme here. -->
    <item name="colorPrimary">@color/colorPrimary</item>
    <item name="colorPrimaryDark">@color/colorPrimaryDark</item>
    <item name="colorAccent">@color/colorAccent</item>
    <item name="android:windowBackground">@color/background_color</item>
    <item name="android:textColor">@color/textColor</item>
</style>
```

This is my app I use this style and it works properly

Comment: what if i need to define custom as cell color? i.e. <item name="android:cellColor">@color/cellColor</item> . Here android does not take cellColor,

Comment: do it in your xml it is for global setting

Comment: i used android:background="@color/cellColor" in xml but it does works on only android device theme i.e not in app theme switching.

Answer (score 0):

AppCompatDelegate.setDefaultNightMode(...) works for AppCompatActivity only (not working for Activity or FragmentActivity), so check parent activity firstly.